# Efficient way of dropping dictionary from a list without mentioning the keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

What is an efficient way of dropping dictionary from a list of dictionaries, if any one of the value in a dictionary is empty?

```
input = [{'mac': '', 'location': '801'}, 
         {'mac': 'E464EECBA5EB', 'location': '816'}, 
         {'mac': '', 'location': '817'}, 
         {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'}, 
         {'mac': 'GH12TY674RF1', 'location': ''}, 
         {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '820'}]


expected_output = [{'mac': 'E464EECBA5EB', 'location': '816'},
                   {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'}, 
                   {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '820'}]
```

Comment: @Fozoro, The post which you have mentioned is to drop a specific key i.e., "id"

Comment: I see, just removed the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
input_list = [{'mac': '', 'location': '801'}, 
              {'mac': 'E464EECBA5EB', 'location': '816'}, 
              {'mac': '', 'location': '817'}, 
              {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'}, 
              {'mac': 'GH12TY674RF1', 'location': ''}, 
              {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '820'}]


expected_output = [d for d in input_list if all(d.values())]
```

Output:

```
[{'mac': 'E464EECBA5EB', 'location': '816'},
 {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '818'},
 {'mac': 'DCE83F3BC820', 'location': '820'}]
```